# mediawiki DBLoadBalancer error while setting up wiki

Tags: mediawiki

I've just installed MediaWiki 1.28 on arch linux with nginx 1.10.3, php 7.1.1, php-fpm, and sqlite 3.16.2. I followed the arch wiki guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MediaWiki. I've installed the required PHP extensions and PHP, sqlite, nginx all seem to run fine on their own.

Now when I'm trying to do the setting up LocalSettings.php part of the MediaWiki installation, I go to 0.0.0.0/mediawiki in the browser, click the setup and get the error below. Maybe it's a setting for sqlite that has to be enabled?

```
[1449c8c65e65734059748f4e] /mw-config/index.php MediaWiki\Services\ServiceDisabledException from line 340 of /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/services/ServiceContainer.php: Service disabled: DBLoadBalancer

Backtrace:

#0 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/MediaWikiServices.php(509): MediaWiki\Services\ServiceContainer->getService(string)
#1 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/GlobalFunctions.php(3089): MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices->getDBLoadBalancer()
#2 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/GlobalFunctions.php(3075): wfGetLB(boolean)
#3 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/cache/LinkCache.php(267): wfGetDB(integer)
#4 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/Title.php(3184): LinkCache->addLinkObj(Title)
#5 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/Title.php(934): Title->getArticleID(integer)
#6 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/content/ContentHandler.php(282): Title->getContentModel()
#7 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/Title.php(4684): ContentHandler::getForTitle(Title)
#8 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(867): Title->getPageLanguage()
#9 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(2110): Parser->getTargetLanguage()
#10 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(2075): Parser->replaceInternalLinks2(string)
#11 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(1290): Parser->replaceInternalLinks(string)
#12 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(441): Parser->internalParse(string)
#13 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/installer/Installer.php(675): Parser->parse(string, Title, ParserOptions, boolean)
#14 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/installer/WebInstaller.php(681): Installer->parse(string, boolean)
#15 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/installer/WebInstaller.php(657): WebInstaller->getInfoBox(string, string, string)
#16 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/installer/WebInstaller.php(401): WebInstaller->getErrorBox(string)
#17 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/mw-config/index.php(54): WebInstaller->showError(Message, string)
#18 /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/mw-config/index.php(38): wfInstallerMain()
#19 {main}
```

Comment: Recently I encountered exactly the same issue, unfortunately I can't remember how exactly it was solved. It's definitely related to missing system component or even wrong directory permissions.

Following error log it seems that WebInstaller fails at starting a PHP session for your request and `ServiceDisabledException` is just an additional error.

See `/index.php` line 54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had my `php/sessions` directory in `/tmp`. I moved it to `session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/sessions"` in `php.ini` and repeated these steps:

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/php/sessions
chown http:http /var/lib/php/sessions
chmod go-rwx /var/lib/php/sessions
```

Comment: MediaWiki 1.27+ does not use the PHP session backend at all. This error is almost certainly unrelated to your session settings. [Filed a bug](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T157890) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what Tgr said above, fixing the sessions did fix the issue for me. I'm using Apache ITK so the resolution I use is slightly different since each virtual host runs under its own unique uid.

First I create a separate directory for the sessions and change ownership

```
mkdir /var/lib/php/sessions-wiki
chown wiki. /var/lib/php/sessions-wiki
```

Then in my VirtualHosts directive I tell Apache/php where to find the session files by adding

```
php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/lib/php/sessions-wiki"
```

Then to make sure your config didn't break it.

```
apachectl configtest
```

Finally reload your config

```
apachectl graceful
```