# cryptic error DBLoadBalancer error while setting up MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I'm experiencing a weird error while trying to install MediaWiki v1.28.1 on MacOSX El Capitan. My stack is Apache 2.4.18,  PHP 7.1 & MySQL 5.7

When trying to do the web installation from localhost, a message displays saying 'LocalSettings.php not found.' however below it is a link to set up the wiki. When i click this link I get a stack trace that I cant get to to the bottom of. The screen lists a deprecated function mycrypt_create_iv() message and also complains about **ServiceContainer.php : Service disabled: DBLoadBalancer**
I've done some searching and this seems to be a common problem and the solution is allegedly related to folder permissions for php sessions. See [Similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42105209/mediawiki-dbloadbalancer-error-while-setting-up-wiki)

My PHP INI 'session.save_path': /var/lib/php/sessions
I've ensured this location is readable and writable using chmod 777 (rwx for all) on this folder. I seem to get a sess_* file created in this location but it is always empty.
I've created a test php script that runs on the same web server and starts a session and writes to a session file in the /var/lib/php/sessions location and this works fine. So I'm not sure if this is permission related in this case? I have also given the htdocs location in my case called mediawiki and it's subfolder and files full read and write ability using chmod 777.

I have run out of ideas after a full day of investigation. I dont know what I dont know :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I downloaded the latest version (1.29 alpha) of MediaWiki from Git and installed it on the same stack as the 1.28.1 that was experienicng the crptic error. Anyway the error is gone, so I'm guessing the developers have a fix on the way which be available in version 1.29
Still does'nt resolve the originall issue with 1.28.1 but does give hope for newer versions going forward